# Google Sheet is not overwriting data with new API request at various frequencies when new data is available (15 minutes, 5 minutes etc)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Is my code missing something?  It works if the sheet is empty, but if there is data already there it will not update until about an hour which I believe is by default. I want the trigger to work. I have already added a timedriven trigger in "Triggers" as well, but when I run my API request the sheet does not change.

Apps Scripts Code:

function myFunction() {

SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1').setValue('=importdata("https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects/tp8m7vXj5TST/last_ready_run/data?api_key=API_KEYf&format=csv")')

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMPORTDATA formula update interval is about an hour, as [it is documented](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?sjid=9589020859082257047-EU#zippy=%2Cchoose-how-often-formulas-calculate). But you still can force the update using the following code:

```
const F = '=IMPORTDATA("https://www.parsehub.com/api/...")';
function myFunction() {
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
    cell.clearContent();    // delete the formula
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // remove cashed results entirely
    cell.setFormula(F);     // write the same formula again
}
```

If you do it too frequently, then you might meet other quota restrictions.
Another alternative is to use [UrlFetchApp's methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app?hl=ru#methods). They will require an additional data parsing code.